# In MS Word, "... is not a valid special character for the Replace With box."

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, find-and-replace

It's the first time I'm giving a question here.
There's text like this:

```
...sometextsometext(sometext)...
```

And I wanted to change it all found in the text by the Replace With tool using its special symbols like this:

```
...sometextsometext (sometext) sometextsometext...
```

I used the ^? (any character) special symbol, but get the message "... is not a valid special character for the Replace With box."

For more details: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msEcD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is use *regular expressions*, also called regex. MS Word has some limited [capability to use regex](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/PowerUser_MSOffice.html), but, "Word supports regex in its own unique way!" So, if you don't mind operating on the unformatted text itself, use a third-party tool, such as free [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), which offer a more complete set of regex tools.

Comment: WOW! An answer!  I-I'm s-sorry, never thought I'd get it so quickly )) I see! regex, right? Now I got it, thank you! I'll try to do so, but I never thought that MS Word has less capability for the regex... Since I familiar with Notepad++, I think I'll get used to regex in it quickly.